# Why the RAM 23lc1024 is not responding or give error?

Tags: embedded, ram, atmega328p, avr-gcc

I interfaced the [23LC1024](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005142C.pdf) RAM module to atmega328. I have coded using embedded c on avr studio. The program flows like one byte is written to the address 0x000000 and Read data from the address 0x000000. But what happened is that, we are getting wrong data while read it.

```
#define F_CPU 11059200UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "23lc1024.h"

int main(void)
{

 SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR);
   SPSR |= (1<<SPI2X);
   
   DDR_23LC |= (1<<CS_23LC);
   DDR_23LC |= (1<<HOLD_23LC);
   DDR_23LC |= 1<<SI_23LC | 1<<SCK_23LC;  //mosi sck as output
   DDR_23LC &= ~(1<<SO_23LC);  //miso input
   
   PORT_23LC |= (1<<HOLD_23LC); //hold is not used
   PORT_23LC |= (1<<CS_23LC); //disable ram
   
   char d;
   //SPDR = 0x00;
   
   PORT_23LC &= ~(1<<CS_23LC); // enable cs of 23lc
   
   SPDR = 0x01; //Write mode register
   while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF)));
   
   SPDR = 0x00;
   while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //Byte mode
   
   SPDR = 0x02;
   while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //write command
   
   SPDR = 0x00; 
   while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //high byte address
   
   SPDR = 0x00;
   while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //second 8 bits address
   
   SPDR = 0x00;
   while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //last 8bits address
   
   SPDR = 'A';
   while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //data 1 byte written
   
   PORT_23LC |= (1<<CS_23LC); // disable ram
   
   //read start
   
    PORT_23LC &= ~(1<<CS_23LC);///\ enable ram
    
    
    SPDR = 0x01; //Write mode register
    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF)));
    
    SPDR = 0x00;
    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //Byte mode
    
    SPDR = 0x03;
    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //read command
    
    SPDR = 0x00;
    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //high byte address
    
    SPDR = 0x00;
    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //second 8 bits address
    
    SPDR = 0x00;
    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //last 8bits address
    
    SPDR = 0x00;
    while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF))); //data read
    d = SPDR;
    
    
    PORT_23LC |= (1<<CS_23LC);
    

   
   
}
```

Can you please find the issue in the code?

[ Edit ]

As per some suggestion, I modified the code and it is given below. But the RAM is not responding ok. When i try to write data at location 0x000000, the data is actually written at 0x1FFFF. In the code below, I written 0x43 data to 0x000000. When the data is read from 0x000000, it shows 0x00. But when read it from 0x01FFFF, the data shows 0x43.

```
#define F_CPU 11059200UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BAUDRATE 9600//115200
#define BAUD_PRESCALLER (((F_CPU / (BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)
void mega_init()
{
    UCSR0C|=(1<<UCSZ00)|(1<<UCSZ01);// 8bit transmission(UCSZ02 in B register); also select asynchronous mode, 1 stop bit
    UBRR0H=(uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER>>8);
    UBRR0L=(uint8_t)BAUD_PRESCALLER;
    UCSR0B|=(1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);// enbale reciever and transmitter
}

void sendstring(char *aaa)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;aaa[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        uart_transmit(aaa[i]);
    }
}


char convertchar(uint8_t n){
    
    char c;
    switch(n){
        
        case 0x00 : c='0';break;
        case 0x01 : c='1';break;
        case 0x02 : c='2';break;
        case 0x03 : c='3';break;
        case 0x04 : c='4'; break;
        case 0x05 : c='5';break;
        case 0x06 : c='6';break;
        case 0x07 : c='7';break;
        case 0x08 : c='8';break;
        case 0x09 : c='9';break;
        case 0x0A : c='A';break;
        case 0x0B : c='B';break;
        case 0x0C : c='C';break;
        case 0x0D : c='D';break;
        case 0x0E : c='E';break;
        case 0x0F : c='F';break;
    }
    
    return(c);
}
void sendinchar(uint8_t num)
{
    
    char a[3]; char c;
    
    
    c=convertchar(num & 0x0F);
    a[1]=c;
    c=convertchar((num & 0xF0)>>4);
    a[0]=c;
    
    a[2]=0x00;
    sendstring(a);
}

#define PORT_23LC PORTB
#define DDR_23LC DDRB

#define CS_23LC PORTB2
#define SO_23LC PORTB4
#define SI_23LC PORTB3
#define SCK_23LC PORTB5
#define HOLD_23LC PORTB1

// set CS to 0 = active
#define RAMACTIVE PORT_23LC&=~(1<<CS_23LC)
// set CS to 1 = passive
#define RAMPASSIVE PORT_23LC|=(1<<CS_23LC)

#define waitspi() while(!(SPSR&(1<<SPIF)))

// Instruction Set -- from data sheet
#define READ      0x03                     /* read memory */
#define WRITE     0x02                 /* write to memory */

#define RDMR 0x05       /* Read Mode Register */
#define WRMR 0x01       /* Write Mode Register */

#define BYTE_MODE       0x00
#define PAGE_MODE       0x80
#define SEQUENTIAL_MODE 0x40


void send32bit(uint32_t address){
    
    sendinchar((uint8_t) (address >> 16));
    sendinchar((uint8_t) (address >> 8));
    sendinchar((uint8_t) (address));
    
    
}
void initSPI()
{
    
    DDR_23LC |= (1<<CS_23LC);
    RAMPASSIVE;
    
    DDR_23LC |= (1<<HOLD_23LC);    //hold pin as output
    DDR_23LC |= 1<<SI_23LC | 1<<SCK_23LC;  //mosi sck as output
    DDR_23LC &= ~(1<<SO_23LC);  //miso input
    
    PORT_23LC &= ~(1<<SI_23LC);
    PORT_23LC &= ~(1<<SCK_23LC);
    PORT_23LC |= (1<<HOLD_23LC);    //HOLD is high when not used
    
    // initialize SPI interface
    // master mode and Fosc/2 clock:
    SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR);
    SPSR |= (1<<SPI2X);
    
    
}

void setRamMode(uint8_t mode)
{
    RAMACTIVE;
    spiTransfer(WRMR);
    spiTransfer(mode);
    RAMPASSIVE;

}


void spiTransfer(unsigned int data)
{
    SPDR = data;
    waitspi();
}
uint8_t readByte(uint32_t address)
{
    send32bit(address);
    RAMACTIVE;
    spiTransfer(READ);
    
    spiTransfer((uint8_t) (address >> 16));            // send high byte of address
    spiTransfer((uint8_t) (address >> 8));             // send middle byte of address
    spiTransfer((uint8_t) (address));
    
    
    spiTransfer(0);
    RAMPASSIVE;
    
    return(SPDR);
    
}

void writeByte(uint32_t address, uint8_t data)
{
    send32bit(address);
    RAMACTIVE;  
    spiTransfer(WRITE);
    spiTransfer((uint8_t) (address >> 16));            // send high byte of address
    spiTransfer((uint8_t) (address >> 8));             // send middle byte of address
    spiTransfer((uint8_t) (address));
    
    spiTransfer(data);
    RAMPASSIVE;
    
}


int main(void)
{
    DDRC |= (1<<PORTC5);
    PORTC |= (1<<PORTC5);
    _delay_ms(2000);
   char d=0x89;
   
   initSPI();
   mega_init();
   
   setRamMode(SEQUENTIAL_MODE);
   
   sendstring("writting byte 0x43....\n\r");
   sendinchar(d);
   
   writeByte(0x000000,0x43);
   
   sendstring("\n\rReading byte...\n\r");
   
   d=readByte(0x000000);
   
   sendinchar(d);
   
   d=readByte(0x01FFFF);

   sendinchar(d);
   
   if(d==0x43){
       
       for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
       {
           PORTC &= ~(1<<PORTC5);
           _delay_ms(2000);
           PORTC |= (1<<PORTC5);
           _delay_ms(2000);
       }
   }
   
   
   
}
```

Comment: What *do* you read?   And how do you even know?  Your code does not attempt to do anything with the result.   Get a cheapie USB-based logic analyzer to use with sigrok.   Try leaving the RAM unselected for a minute and loop the MOSI back to MISO and and change your code to see that you read what you write.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @ChrisStratton what do you mean by nothing? This is the code to write a byte into RAM location 0x000000 and read the byte from it.

Comment: Again, you you do  *nothing* with the value alledgedly read, so how do you even know what it is?  Did you post code other than what you are actually using?

Comment: @ChrisStratton  I am not clear. Can you explain it more? what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok sorry. That was a typo and it was changed for testing. Now I corrected the functions readByte and writeByte. Please check it

Comment: Try writing and reading at a location NOT on a memory boundary. What happens? Without looking at the code this could be due to a 16 bit two address location write, or a pre-write-increment write via a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct framing. Only one command can be sent in one transaction, and you are sending multiple commands in one transaction.

Correct sequence is CS low, one command and it's data (if it has data), CS high.

Wait for completion if necessary, only then send another command.

Comment: I am doing the same, right?. Did you know about the RAM 23lc1024? I used the commands in it.

Comment: I have set the Ram mode to Byte mode. Then giving read/write command and after that the corresponding address.

Comment: No you are not. You are sending the mode command and then read/write command during the same chip select. The flash chip will not understand that. Chip select must go high after each and every command to start command execution.

Comment: So you are saying I have to give 1. select chip 2. command 3. deselect for every commands?

Comment: What about data?

Comment: For each command and it's data is a complete transaction. All transactions must be separated with a chip select, because first byte after falling chip select is the command byte, and rising edge of chip select terminates a command like actually executes the write. If the byte is not first after chip select, it is not a command byte.

Comment: So here, setting the mode of transmission have to separate by chip select and the Write command, address, and data transfer can be in one chip select, right?

Comment: They must be, otherwise the write command will be incomplete. Look at the datasheet diagrams for how the basic commands are structured.

Comment: Please find the edits. I have changed as you said. but now I have another poblem.

Comment: Follow the datasheet sequences.

Comment: If the problem in the original question is solved, then it is, and new problems should have a new question. But there is no apparent reason why a write to address 0 would accidentally go to address 0x1ffff, or why reading address 0x1ffff would read address 0.

Comment: If you have done what was suggested and it does not work please provide full detail. If their is a different problem please ask a new question. You can reference this one.